# checking whether shared preference is null or not

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am checking whether a shared preference value is null or not with the help of this code

```
    SharedPreferences myPrefo = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    ostt = myPrefo.getString(Sharedprefse.KEY_FSHD, null);

    if(ostt!= null && !ostt.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(context,"f"+ ostt,                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, ostt+"n",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

My problem is, every time it returns null even if shared preference is not empty

Is this the right process or I have to try some other way??

If the sharedpreference is empty then am fetching a string from a remote server and store it in shared preference

here is my code

```
   if(ostt == null || ostt.matches("") || ostt.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("Remote Address");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    if(!(str==null) || !(str.matches("")) || !(str.isEmpty())) {
                        session.createFS(str);
                    }
                }
```

this is my createFS() function

```
 public void createFS(String str){

    editor.putString(KEY_FSHD, str);


    editor.commit();
  }
```

Comment: How do you know it's not empty?
Maybe there's something wrong in how you set the string to the preferences?

Comment: How do you save the value to the shared preferences?

Comment: post the code of saving to shared prefs

Comment: better IF statement  `if (!TextUtils.isEmpty()) `

Comment: where you put the value show the code.

Comment: have updated my code, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your code:

To save to shared prefs:

```
public void createFS(String str){

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefo", Context.Mode_Private);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

    editor.putString("KEY_FSHD", str);


    editor.commit();
  }
```

While retrieving

```
SharedPreferences myPrefo = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    ostt = myPrefo.getString("KEY_FSHD", null);
```

You will get the required value.

Comment: it force closes the app

Comment: You may be getting null pointer exception, check the value of str?

Comment: yes am getting null pointer exception but only when the app ran for the first time coz in the second run it works fine. How to remove that error??

Comment: Can you guess why this happens? and can you tell me in which line are you getting the error?